# Gecode: constraining integer variables using a float value

Tags: c++, constraint-programming, gecode

I use `Gecode` through its `C++` API in a kind of learning context with positive and negative examples. 
In this context I have two `BoolVarArray`: `positive_bags_` and `negative_bags_`.

And what I want to do seems very simple: I want to constrain these bags with a minimal growth rate constraint based on a user parameter `gmin`.

Thereby, the constraint should look like: `sum(positive_bags_) >= gmin * sum(negative_bags_)`. 
It works using the `rel` function defined like this: `rel(*this, sum(positive_bags_) >= gmin * sum(negative_bags_))` but my problem is that in my case `gmin` is a float but is casted by `rel` as an integer.

Therefore I can only constrain `positive_bags_` to be `2`, `3`, ... times bigger than `negative_bags_` but I need for my experiments to define `gmin` as `1.5` for example.

I checked the documentation and did not find a definition of `linear` that use both `Boolean`/`Integer` and `Float` variables.

Is there some way to define this constraint using a float `gmin`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please point to the documentation of the 'sum' method. It seems your variables are being implicitly cast which creates a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your factor `gmin`can be expressed as a reasonably small rational `n/d` (`3/2` in your example), then you could use

```
d * sum(positive_bags_) >= n * sum(negative_bags_)
```

as your constraint. If there is no small rational that is suitable, then you need to [channel](https://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/group__TaskModelFloatChannel.html) your variables to FloatVars and use the FloatVar [linear constraint](https://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/group__TaskModelFloatLI.html).

Answer (score 0):

If implicit type-casting is an issue you can try:

```
(float) sum(positive_bags_) >= (gmin * (float) sum(negative_bags_))
```

Assuming gmin is a float.

Implicit casting will convert your float to an int. If you want to control what type of rounding you want to apply, wrap the result into `<math.h>`'s `roundf` or a rounding function of your choice depending on the type.

Comment: Sum is a function in Gecode that (in this case) returns an IntExpr, which is not something that can be cast to a float.

Comment: That's what i thought, but i couldn't find the doc on the gecode site easily, hence i asked for a link.